# Pandas Data frame eval function error

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I tried to the following using the pandas eval function

```
df.eval('I = (G * H) / 10000', inplace=True)
```

But it returned me the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'object' and '<class 'int'>'
```

But when I simply did,

```
df.eval('I = G * H', inplace=True)
```

everything worked fine. 
Any idea on how to tackle this?? I want to evaluate much more complex expression using the eval function.

Comment: Are you sure that `G * H` is an entirely numeric column?

Comment: Yes they are entirely numeric

Comment: if you do df['G'] = pd.to_numeric(df['G']) and the same with 'H' before your `eval` function, do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'object' and '<class
> 'int'>'
> ```

suggests that `(G * H)` returns an `object` dtype even though it works with (supposedly) numeric data.

```
my_df.eval('I = (A * B)', inplace=True)
print(my_df.I)
>>> 0    8
>>> Name: I, dtype: object
```

Check your columns `dtype` and possibly convert to a numeric one.

```
import pandas as pd


columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
my_df.loc[len(my_df)] = [2, 4, 5]
print(my_df.dtypes)

>>> A    object
>>> B    object
>>> C    object
>>> dtype: object

# Convert from object to int.
my_df[columns] = my_df[columns].astype(int)

my_df.eval('I = (A * B) / 10000', inplace=True)
print(my_df)
>>>    A  B  C       I
>>> 0  2  4  5  0.0008
```